# Fixed Menu Bar for website

Tags: css, menu, scroll, fixed, parallax

Okay, i have been creating myself a parallax scrolling website and i cant figure out to make the fixed menu bar.

I want the menu bar to appear 2/3 sections down the website and as the user scrolls past that page I want it to become fixed to the top of the page as they scroll down the remainder of the page. Sorry if my terminology is terrible, if it helps i want the menu bar to function exactly as the one on this web page does.

So basically i have no idea how to do this in css, so if someone could help that would be great.

http://alwayscreative.net/

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you already Googled something? Before opening a thread? What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Could [THIS](http://www.techknowlogists.com/how-to-create-sticky-navigation-bar/) put you into the right direction?
Or [ANOTHER](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints/) one

```
<div class="header"><strong>Header</strong></div>
<div class="nav"><strong>Navigation Bar</strong></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<style>
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.header{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 3%;
}
.nav{
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #D7D7D7;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.content{
    height: 1200px;
}
</style>
```

Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = 90;
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= scrollTop){
            $('.nav').css({
                position : 'fixed',
                top : '0'
            });
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() < scrollTop){
            $('.nav').removeAttr('style');  
        }
    })
})</script>
```